# Difference Encoding using Protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

Is there a way to serialize an object with Protobuf-net such that a call like the one below, will update only the values in the dataBlob which changed?

```
var dataBlob = <previous values>;
testTypeModel.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, dataBlob, typeof(DataBlob), PrefixStyle.Base128, 0, null);
```

For example:

```
var dataBlob = new DataBlob { a = 6, b = "Hello World" }
var newDataBlob = new DataBlob { a = 6, b = null }

//Expected data on the wire
var wireBlob = new DataBlob { b = null };

DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(wireBlob, dataBlob, typeof(DataBlob), PrefixStyle.Base128, 0, null);

Assert.AreEqual(newBlob, dataBlob);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can track which fields have changed: sure, you can use conditional serialization to achieve this. The most basic way would be, for property `Foo`,  to provide a `bool ShouldSerializeFoo()` method (a pre-existing convention that protobuf-net supports). The `Merge` / `Deserialize` methods (depending on the API used) support passing in a preexisting instance.

Note that lists are always additive.

However, protobuf-net will make no attempt to track changes itself.

Comment: How about the case when the field becomes null?

Comment: @Paul the concept of null does not exist in the ProtoBuf specification. There is no way to convey that.